# Java equivalent to Matlab's `eps` or Numpy/Python's `spacing` function (floating-point relative accuracy)

Tags: java, python, matlab, floating-point, floating-accuracy

### Background

Matlab's built-in `eps` function [1] can take a numeric value `X` and return "the positive distance from `abs(X)` to the next larger in magnitude floating point number of the same precision".

```
>> eps(1)
ans =
   2.2204e-16
>> eps(single(1))
ans =
   1.1921e-07
>> eps(1e6)
ans =
   1.1642e-10
>> eps(single(1e6))
ans =
       0.0625
```

Equivalently, Numpy provides the `spacing` function [2]:

```
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [19]: np.spacing(1)
Out[19]: 2.2204460492503131e-16

In [20]: np.spacing(np.single(1))
Out[20]: 1.1920929e-07

In [21]: np.spacing(1e6)
Out[21]: 1.1641532182693481e-10

In [22]: np.spacing(np.single(1e6))
Out[22]: 0.0625
```

### Question

Is there an equivalent function in Java (and therefore JVM languages like Clojure)?

### References

- [1] http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html
- [2] Documentation at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/code_generators/ufunc_docstrings.py#L2905.

  - The actual function implementation in C seems to be at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c.src#L323 (the license banner before npy_nextafter gives my question some irony).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [java.lang.math.ulp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29):

> Returns the size of an ulp of the argument. An ulp of a `double` value
>   is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the
>   `double` value next larger in magnitude. Note that for non-NaN x,
>   `ulp(-x) == ulp(x)`

Also, available for [floats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28float%29). Some [background on ULPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

Comment: Numpy's source code referenced a function "nextafter" which is available in C++, and also, I discovered, Java---but ulp is simpler! This is, I think, the answer to many epsilon-related Java questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AhmedFasih: Yes, if you read the introduction to `java.lang.math` or many of the details of the functions included, you see that tolerances are described with respect to `ulps`. This is very common in numerics and pervasive in Matlab.